# single-user group method in signalr

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Is there any disadvantage if we use single-user group method instead of keeping identity and connections in a list as mentioned in below link. If so we can avoid keeping connections in memory or database. Please advice, will this make any issue with web farm.

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you can map one connection to one or more groups. And this mapping should be mostly depending on your need. For example, whether to notify only a single user about a change or a group of users.

However, this might be problematic for web farm scenario. To scale out, you can use a backplane, where each application publishes to the backplane and backplane forwards to notification to all instances of the application (servers in the web farm). There are 3 possible options for backplanes: Azure service bus, Redis, and SQL server.

You may check https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr for more information.

Comment: Thank you, can we do backplane in MySQL?

Comment: Or can we mention mysql connectionstring in dependency resolver.
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);

Comment: I have never tried it (not even SQL server, my preferred backplane is Redis, though I am yet to use that too). However, this mechanism uses service broker of SQL Server, and I am not sure whether something similar can be done with MySQL or not, as I have not used MySQL much. Maybe that demands another question :)